# Connecting EEG device to Azure Machine Learning studio

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I did some researches and video to figure out how to connect EEG devices which is Emotiv Insight in real-time to Microsoft Azure Machine Learning Studio.

I thought any ways to do it, perhaps I need to connect to other services before connecting to Azure studio.

My aim is making an app taken brainwave and use Azure studio to analyze it. Finally, data is saved to firebase and response to my app.

However, I am stucking to find a way to connect my EEG data to Azure. It is appreciated for anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Emotive use a service, running on the cortex process. You need a websocket to talk with it. Additionaly all communication to and from the service is using JSon objects. Then you need to transport that into Azure